# Extract class content from html page

Tags: html, class, extract

I have the source code of an html page and what i want to do is extract selective informations from it. For example, there is in the source code this:

```
 <div class="date">
 <strong>Date:</strong> 03/04/2015 </div>
```

and what i want to extract is 'Date: 03/04/2015'

or this:

```
<div class="name">
    <strong>Name:</strong> <a href = 'http://www.example.com' title='Title'>Jhon Smit</a >
```

and I want to extract 'Jhon Smit'
, this operation for a lot of things in the page. Is there a fast way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) property of the element.

By the way, `DL` list is more suitable to markup this sort of things:

```
<dl class="name">
    <dt>Name:</dt>
    <dd><a href="http://www.example.com">Jhon Smit</a></dd>
</dl>
```